# Can someone please clear the difference between @GetMapping and @PostMapping in spring also can we use these annotations at one another's place?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

for example to save the details of employee:

```
@PostMapping("/url")
public void addEmployee(EmployeeBean emp){
....
}

@GetMapping("/url")
public void addEmployee(EmployeeBean emp){
....
}
```

Can I do this?

Comment: If the method signatures are the same, then no.

Comment: The GetMapping annotion handles a GET request, while PostMapping handles a POST request.  You should not be using a GET call to persist data though - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods.

Comment: How will you pass the body for GETrequest?

Comment: To elaborate on Jan's comment, your GET method will most definitely not do the same as the POST. Your GetMapping `addEmployee` is wrongly named, that method will only retrieve an employee, never add.

Comment: Simon... but i can use @postmapping to fatch the values right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **All mapping are specialized version of @RequestMapping annotation that
>   acts as a shortcut for @RequestMapping(method =
>   RequestMethod.GET/POST/PUT/DELETE)**

```
@GetMapping - shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PostMapping - shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PutMapping - shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@DeleteMapping - shortcut for @RequestMapping(method =RequestMethod.DELETE)

@PostMapping – Handle HTTP POST Requests
@GetMapping – Handle HTTP Get Requests
@PutMapping – Handle HTTP Put Requests
@DeleteMapping – Handle HTTP Delete Requests
```

***Technically speaking you can use the annotation at each other's place
   but each annotation is created for the purpose.***

- Like to handle the HTTP Get requests and get the data only  use
  @GetMapping
- To perform add/update operation, use HTTP POST/PUT request i.e.
  @PostMapping or @PutMapping
- And to perform delete operation, use HTTP  Delete request i.e. @DeleteMapping annotation.

Comment: for ex: @PostMapping("/url")
             public List<Employee> getEmployeeList(){...}
     I will be able to get the data in this scenario? if yes then why?

Comment: Yes i mentioned in the bold that technically you can use annotation at other's place because they all are extending the properties of requestmapping whose purpose is to serve all the request. But when you define the specific request as GET or POST then it help request handler to understand what kind of operation is primary focus. If you perform the GET operation on POST then also it will work. These are just the guidelines for web development

Answer (score 1):

@GetMapping is used for HTTP Get request and @PostMapping is used for HTTP Post request.
To read more about please go through below links:

https://learnjava.co.in/spring-requestmapping-getmapping-and-postmapping-annotations/

http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/must-know-spring-boot-annotations-controllers/

Comment: I have already checked these links but i have no clarification that can i  use @PostMapping for fetch type request or not.
if yes then why? if no then why?

Answer (score 0):

`@PostMapping` is shortcut for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)` and `@GetMapping`is for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`

In case of adding an entity, post is preferred as you can pass data in body,

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public void addEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeBean emp){
....
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: and what if I use @PostMapping for fetch request?

Comment: You can use the post method for fetch as well. Usecase would be you have many input parameters.